# Hide only on menu click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on navigation of menu items. On mouse over of my menu item, it will extend and go out on mouse out. I made it to be in extended position until we click on the out out side of the menu item. However I need only on click of other menu item.

For example, if I click on any menu item it will be fixed position, but it should move in when I click on any other item.

Currently whereever I click on the window, it's hiding. But the requirement is like it should hide only whenever we click on other menu Item only.

[Click here for image ref](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZlLk.png)

```css
#mySidenav a {
  position: absolute;
  left: -80px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}

#mySidenav a:focus {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
}

#mySidenav a:hover {
  left: 0;
}

#about {
  top: 20px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

#blog {
  top: 80px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

#projects {
  top: 140px;
  background-color: #f44336;
}

#contact {
  top: 200px;
  background-color: #555
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="#" id="about">About</a>
  <a href="#" id="blog">Blog</a>
  <a href="#" id="projects">Projects</a>
  <a href="#" id="contact">Contact</a>
</div>
```

Comment: could you put this in a snippet please?

Comment: place some screenshots of what you want

Comment: you're working with `#mySidenav a:focus` thats why you menu items lose the fixed position as soon as you click anywhere else than the item itself. the easiest way here is to add a new class to your elements on click e.g. `$("#mySidenav a").on("click",function(e){//add class and remove old one})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using extra class for example:

```js
$('#mySidenav a').on('click', function() {
  $('a.fixed').removeClass('fixed');
  $(this).addClass('fixed');
});
```

```css
#mySidenav a {
  position: absolute;
  left: -80px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}

#mySidenav a:focus,
#mySidenav a.fixed{
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
}

#mySidenav a:hover {
  left: 0;
}

#about {
  top: 20px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

#blog {
  top: 80px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

#projects {
  top: 140px;
  background-color: #f44336;
}

#contact {
  top: 200px;
  background-color: #555
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="#" id="about">About</a>
  <a href="#" id="blog">Blog</a>
  <a href="#" id="projects">Projects</a>
  <a href="#" id="contact">Contact</a>
</div>

<div style="margin-left:80px;">
  <h2>Hoverable Sidenav Buttons</h2>
  <p>Hover over the buttons in the left side navigation to open them.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Be careful here. That would add the fixed on click class to every `a` on page because of `$(document)`. You should use `$("#mySidenav")`

Comment: @Nitro.de Right! fixed

Comment: Yes, Understood. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need a bit of Javascript here!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#mySidenav a').on('click', function() {
    $('#mySidenav a').removeClass('fix');
    $(this).addClass('fix');
  });
});
```

```css
#mySidenav a {
  position: absolute;
  left: -80px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}

#mySidenav a.fix {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
}

#mySidenav a:hover {
  left: 0;
}

#about {
  top: 20px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

#blog {
  top: 80px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

#projects {
  top: 140px;
  background-color: #f44336;
}

#contact {
  top: 200px;
  background-color: #555
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="#" id="about">About</a>
  <a href="#" id="blog">Blog</a>
  <a href="#" id="projects">Projects</a>
  <a href="#" id="contact">Contact</a>
</div>
```